# OCX control not loading into IDC_Explorer Web control;

Tags: desktop-bridge

My app brings up a window that has a Web Control inside it.  The web control is passed an html page to display.  On the page is a  tag that loads an OCX. The ocx is located in the same folder as the application.  In the non UWP version this all worked because the OCX is registered and the appropriate entries are  made in the System Registery. As we know the registery works differently in a UWP Bridge App. It appears the converter caught and made the correct entries in the "Registry.data" file. If I retrieve the entries (using the GUID of the OCX) using code inside the app the  values look correct.  I suspect that the App is looking inside the "Registry.data" file but the Web Control is looking in the System registry and does not find the OCX.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Neil

Comment: Could you please tell more details about your currently app? For example, What is the app before convert? What's your app target version?  And also please provide some environment information. What's your windows 10 OS version? Additionally, just for confirm, is the OCX you mentioned here "Object Linking and Embedding (OLE) Control Extension"?

Comment: The app worked fine before the Desktop Bridge conversion.  The ocx brings up a simple spread sheet inside an HTML Page.

Comment: Details:

Windows SDK version:10.0.17134.0

Visual Studio:  15.8.0 Preview 2

OS: Windows 10 version 1803

32 Bit App